# Equilibrium Temperature

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

There are two container. First container has water at $100°C$ with $200g$, second container has water at $200°C$ with $100g$. How do i calcuate equilibarium temperature? (They are mixed)

Comment: Yeah, It's mixed.

Comment: Well you could do a weighted average...

Comment: Masses and temperatures not equal with each other. Because Of this I couldn't solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. You should do a weighted average:$$T=\frac{2}{3}100+\frac{1}{3}200=133.33°C$$
In other words, you have $200 g$ of water at $100°C$ and $100 g$ at $200°C$. So $$T=\frac{200*100+100*200}{300}$$

Comment: Why is   T = $2/3$?

Comment: I never put $T=2/3$ . Please read the entire equality

Comment: I'm sorry for that, why you hit with it?

Comment: Lol I just didn't understand why $2/3$

Comment: Because two thirds of the whole mass is at $100°C$

Comment: Still don't understand $2/3$ and $1/3$ can you write about that ?

Comment: Imagine you have two guys in front of you who are 2meters tall and 1 guy is 1.80m tall. In average, how tall are there ? You just do $H=\frac {2+2+1.8} {3}$. If you understand this, you understand your initial trouble...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Great

Comment: Did you catch it all now? Should I edit my answer?

Comment: If you edit, I become happy.

Comment: Yeah, you are great!

Answer (score 0):

The exchanged heat quantities are
$$
Q_1=m_1c(T-T_1)\\
Q_2=m_2c(T-T_2)
$$
And given that $Q_1+Q_2=0$ this implies 
$$
T=\frac{m_1T_1+m_2T_2}{m_1+m_2}
$$

Comment: I'm not sure @Bamons is waiting for a thermodynamical answer ;-). Although it's correct of course...

Comment: LOL your right.

Comment: beside the explanation, the resulting formula is general and simple enough to be easily applied to the present case.